# How to edit ini directive?

Tags: php, pear, mamp

I'm working on Mac 10.6.6. with php 5.3 installed with MAMP. I've run into a problem trying to install Pear. A blog I found suggested a solution that requires me to to set the following ini directive:

```
detect_unicode = Off
```

Can someone tell me how to do it?

I went looking through MAMP folder but couldn't see PHP ini file. Note, I'm very inexperienced working with the command line.

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under (assuming a default install)...

```
Macintosh HD / Applications / MAMP / conf / php5 / php.ini
```

You then open this file in a text editor and modify the text to suit. Save it and restart Apache.

Alternatively, some options can be set from PHP itself with `ini_set()`. Some can not for security reasons, such as [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

Comment: thanks a lot. Looking in my php.ini file, there is no detect_unicode setting. Do you think I can just add it? or can you only manipulate settings that are already in the file?

Comment: @Micheal You should be able to add it, if it isn't present. If it's a problem, I'm sure PHP will tell you :)

Comment: @Micheal I assume you mean *nothing bad happened* ?

Comment: yes, nothing bad happened, but also nothing good happened in that it didn't fix my problem with installing Pear.